# Solving the number of integer non negative solutions for the following system:

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, cardinals

I don't know how to solve for the number of integer non negative solutions of following system:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}{x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=6} \\ {x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=27}\end{array}\right.
$$
I do know how to solve them separately but not when they are joint.

**Advancements(I):**

I realized later that I could look at this as if I was to solve another system of equations:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}{x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=6} \\ {x_{1}+x_{2}=21}\end{array}\right.
$$

The number of solutions for each equation are ${8 \choose 2}$ and ${22 \choose 1}$ respectively. So would the solution be ${8 \choose 2}+{22 \choose 1}=28+22=50$?

**Advancements(II):**

The previous reasoning is wrong, I think this is it:

I obtain the solutions for $x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=6$ which is ${8 \choose 2}= 28.$

Since this equations determines the second, these are the solutions for the system.

Comment: Subtracting the top from the bottom gives $x_1+x_2=21$, now you can solve separately.

Comment: I think I just noticed exactly what you said, is that it?

Comment: Well, the separation part, yes.  But having solved the equations separately, you don't add.  Think about it.

Comment: But I am asked the number of solutions for the system so I should give just one number, right?

Comment: Yes, but that's not obtained by adding.  You can pair any solution to the first with any solution to the second so...

Comment: Suppose you had the system $x_1=1$, $x_2=1$.  One solution to each, clearly.  Would you then conclude that there are $1+1=2$ solutions to the simultaneous system?

Comment: Yes, I do understand that. But I think I am not asked for the solutions of each equations but for the number of elements $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ that satisfy the system.

Comment: No one is disputing that.  Try a simple case.  $x_1+x_2=2$ and $x_3+x_4=1$.  How many solutions separately?  How many solutions for the simultaneous system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly found that the "advanced" equations have $\binom82$ and $\binom{22}1$ solutions, respectively. Since you can combine any triple which is a solution to the first equation with any pair which is a solution to the second equation the overall number of solutions is
$$\binom82\binom{22}1.$$